# Ionic pushing to Array gives [object Object] instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

Got this function

```
drawCircle(pointa, pointb, radius, dir) { 
    console.log("TESTING POINTA POINTB >>>>>>>>>>>>"+pointa+" - "+pointb);
    let lat;
    let lng;
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
    var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
    var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles or 6371 in km
    var points = 32; 

    // find the raidus in lat/lon 
    var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
    var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(pointa * d2r); 

    var extp = new Array(); 
    if (dir==1)   {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the ends
    else      {var start=points+1;var end=0}
    for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir) { 

      var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
      let ey = pointb + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
      let ex = pointa + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
      extp.push({lat: ey, lng: ex}); 
      //console.log("PUSHING TO EXTP >>>>>>>>>>>>",{'lat': ey,'lng': ex});

    } 
    console.log("CHECK EXTP ARRAY >>>>>>>>>>>>",extp);
    return extp;
  }
```

It is supposed to create an array (extp) and return it to the function (this.drawCircle) which I am using in google maps

```
this.map.addPolygon({
                points: this.points,
                  holes: this.drawCircle(this.myLat, this.myLong, 1, 1),
                    'strokeColor': "black",
                    'strokeWidth': 2,
                    'fillColor': "#222222"
                  });
```

However, in the console instead of it giving the values, I am getting objects instead of (for example): {lat: 85,lng: 179.9} in this format- which in return doesn't build the hole in the polygon.

CHECK EXTP ARRAY >>>>>>>>>>>> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

EDIT:

If I replace

```
this.map.addPolygon({
                points: this.points,
                  holes: this.drawCircle(this.myLat, this.myLong, 1, 1),
                    'strokeColor': "black",
                    'strokeWidth': 2,
                    'fillColor': "#222222"
                  });
```

with

```
this.map.addPolygon({
                points: this.points,
                  holes: [
                    [
                        {lat: 29.68224948021748,lng: -23.676965750000022},  
                        {lat: 29.68224948021748,lng: 44.87772174999998}, 
                        {lat: 71.82725578445813,lng: 44.87772174999998}, 
                        {lat: 71.82725578445813,lng: -23.676965750000022}, 

                      ]
                    ],
                    'strokeColor': "black",
                    'strokeWidth': 2,
                    'fillColor': "#222222"
                  });
```

It works fine, so I am presuming that the issue is still due to extp. Any ideas?

Comment: Some browsers convert Objects with ```toString``` when you call console.log, so it is possible that your properties are there. What browser are you using? Can you confirm the type of one your array's objects by printing ```typeof extp[0]``` and also checking to see if that first object has properties

Comment: typeof extp[0]  .... CHECK EXTP TYPEOF >>>>>>>>>>>> object

Comment: And how about logging ```extp[0].lat``` and ```Object.getOwnPropertyNames(extp[0])```

Comment: Doing console.dir(extp[0]) shows {"lat":55.12345678,"lng":25.12345678}

Comment: but the code otherwise works? is it a console issue or?

Comment: try: `console.log("CHECK EXTP ARRAY >>>>>>>>>>>>",JSON.stringify(extp,null,2))`

Comment: It seems that there's no problem here. When you create something `var a = {lat: '123.456'}` it declares an Object with a property 'lat'. Print `console.log(a)` you will get `[object, Object]`, print `console.log(JSON.stringify(a))` you will get `{"lat": "123.456"}`. Same with an Array, `var a = [{}, {}]` will print `[object, Object], [object, Object]` and `[{}, {}]` respectively

Comment: Can you please check the edit above in the main question .. thanks :)